# RelativeLayout children onClick propagation

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, onclicklistener

I have following GUI component: ImageView and TextView inside of RelativeLayout, some kind of compound button. I have selector xml for ImageView background in case someone is clicking on it changes state to clicked. I would like assign click listener to RelativeLayout so it will propagate its click to ImageView and TextView so they will change their state accordingly. How do I achieve this? The problem when I assign click listener to RelativeLayout instead of ImageView its intercepts click and don't change state of ImageView and TextView to simulate click.

Answer (score 2):

Set android:duplicateParentState="true" to all children elements. After that you will have a click propagation.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Use duplicateParentState property set to true.

Comment: Can you add some more details?